# Beginning Codeigniter + phonegap + jquerymobile

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am very interested in using CI phonegap and jquery to make mobile apps, So I've been searching the internet trying to find perhaps an example of using codeigniter with jquery mobile and phonegap(for android specifically) because I have alot of questions.

How I would setup the backend of the site for data input/output and when I goto to put it into eclipse to convert it to Android app, do I include the controllers or only the views + jquery?

I've seen and have been trying to learn more about rest services and curl. I understand I will probrarly be using json, does that mean I can put php code in the html files that phonegap will convert?

Please point me in a good direction, have already checked stackoverflow but not much mentioned other then restservices. thanks

Comment: I think this is a very broad question that could probably be best answer in several smaller questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

And check out JQtouch+zepto instead of JqueryMobile